# Why is my InfoPath 2010 form having styling issues?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath

The form loads well into **SharePoint** and looks proper in **Chrome** and **Firefox** but for some reason my font styles are not applying and my input field settings aren't taking affect in **IE 7** and **8**.

Very frustrating, especially because there's no where to check the code to see if there's some stray tags that should have been cleared out.

Anybody run into this before?

Whats the best method to clean it up?

[image: This is how it is supposed to look (looks like this in Chrome and Firefox]
[image: This is how it looks in IE 7 & 8]

Comment: This is exat duplicate of http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/45911/why-is-my-infopath-2010-form-having-styling-issues

Comment: it's called reaching out to more people. This forum allowed me to post pictures unlike the other one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved. it was a stylesheet issue. the stylesheet was being loaded in twice for some reason. This created this bizarre conflict.

Comment: You should edit your original question and include this information or put it as a comment. Really shouldn't be an answer.